# JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0) in python

Tags: python, html, json, python-3.x, request

Why am I getting this error? Is there another way I can convert this into a json file?

```
import requests
import json

url = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AMZN/balance-sheet?p=AMZN&.tsrc=fin-srch'

r = requests.get(url)
r.json()
```

Comment: Check the status of the response. `r.raise_for_status()` will throw an exception if the request failed

Comment: maybe its not returning json?

Comment: The url you provided doesnt return json, it just returns HTML

Comment: @ChrisDoyle, yes and how do I convert it to json?

Comment: you cant convert it to json its html. Why do you think or expect it to be json?

Comment: @ChrisDoyle Can you use pandas or something else to convert the data table you can see if you click on the link

Comment: you would first need to use an html parse to extract the info you want then you can do what ever you like with the data. However thats another question. I regards to this question, the answer is the error you get is because your response is not json so cant be parsed as json

Answer (score 0):

In short, the URL returns HTML not json, so you cant parse it as JSON. As i said in comments, if there is certain data from this page you want you would need to use an HTML parser to extract that info then you can use what ever code/module you like to analyse, view, edit that data however thats a separate question.